# How to get an associative array from URI path parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, slug, symfony-routing

I'm setting routes using Symfony/Routing component and mapping them to their respective controller and action.

The problem is that some actions (methods) receive more than one parameter and I want to solve this issue passing an array from the parameters set in the URL to the method it is calling.

(I simplified the API for defining routes, so it may seem a little
different in the code examples)

```
 //setting new route
 Route::add('user_introduce_route',
        '/user/{name}/{$age}/{$profession}',
        ['controller' => 'App\Controllers\User.introduce'], 
        ['name' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+', 'age' => '[0-9]+', 'profession' => '[[a-zA-Z]+]']
 );
```

When I navigate through */user/myuser01/programmer* it calls *introduceAction()* set in my *UserController* and I want to pass these three parameters together to the method. Here is how I call the method:

```
public static function startRouting()
{
    $parameters = self::matchUrl(); //UrlMatcher->match()

    $class = explode('.', $parameters['controller'])[0];
    $method = explode('.', $parameters['controller'])[1];

    $class::$method(); //here I would like to pass the array with the parameters
}
```

What I suppose to be done in this situation is to retrieve an associative array from the parameters in the URL and pass to the method that is being called only name, age and profession slugs.

If you can help me or know any other workaround for this issue I appreciate.

Comment: [`$_GET`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) already contains an associative array of GET parameters. That would be the simplest solution IMO

Comment: Isn't GET parameters set only when I have a query string like _/uri/path?name=&age=&profession=_ ?

Comment: That is true. When you said "path parameters" I though that's what you meant. You can explode the URL string and use the forward slash as a delimiter, e.g., `$params = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`. `$params[0]` would be 'user', `$params[1]` would be 'myuser01' and `$params[2]` would be 'programmer' from the path provided in your example

Comment: I get this, but I want something like ['name' => 'myuser01', 'age' => 19, 'profession' => 'programmer'] so I can deal with these values inside my methods.

Comment: Btw what I meant with path parameters is the values I get from _{name}_ or _{age}_

Comment: what's stopping you from just creating your own associative array? for instance `$arr['name'] = 'Joe Bob Briggs';`? Then just send `$arr` to whatever you need to send it to. ("arr" is just a placeholder for a better name)

Comment: Here's a  one liner that would accomplish this: `list($params['name'], $params['age'], $params['profession']) = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` This is making the assumption that the "parameters" always occur in that order.

Comment: What is stopping me sir @dmcoding is how I get the values that comes from the URL. Not only for this example but as you can see I am calling the methods dynamically so I don't have to know how many parameters it is needed. I think there is somewhere a workaround using any other Symfony component but couldn't find for now.

Comment: Hey, man, there's no need to be hostile. It was an honest question, no need to get snippy.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds a little aggressive. I'm just crazy with so many coding. Peace bro.

Comment: doesnt `$parameters` contain exactly the parameters you want, why not unset the controller param (`unset($parameters['controller'])`) and just `$class::$method($parameters);`? am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can tell there are two canonical solutions, where the second one is slightly more elaborate. and a bonus solution, that requires changing your current routing definition approach, but I like that solution way more.

#### use the `$parameters`

since `$parameters` already contains all data from the slug with the correct name, we can just remove / filter out the controller (and other general well-known entries, if you have any):

```
unset($parameters['controller']);
unset($parameters['_route']); // <-- should be there
$class::$method($parameters);
```

#### use the route requirements

I hope you still have the routecollection you provided to the url matcher:

```
$requirements = $routecollection->get($parameters['_route'])->getRequirements();
$reduced = [];
foreach(array_keys($requirements) as $key) {
    // ?? null, in case there are optional route params?
    $reduced[$key] = $parameters[$key] ?? null;
}
$class::$method($reduced);
```

As far as I can tell, every route parameter must be a requirement, so ... yeah. Unless you have some very very very sophisticated routes with weird regular expressions, this should work and is probably future proof regarding adding more non-path parameters to your routes.

#### change your routing (bonus, would be my preference)

the symfony framework uses the routing as well. however, every non-path route parameter is always prefixed with a `_`, which makes it very easy to filter out. If you would change your route definition accordingly (turning `'controller'` into `'_controller'`), you could filter out the params quite easily:

```
//$class = explode('.', $parameters['_controller'])[0];
//$method = explode('.', $parameters['_controller'])[1];
// different here -------------------^^ 

$reduced = [];
foreach($parameters as $key => $value) {
    if($key[0] != '_') { 
        $reduced[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$class::$method($reduced);
```

and routing definition obviously has to be adapted, as mentioned.

Comment: Yeahh thank you for clearing up my mind. I got stuck on that and things got a little messy. I believe that's somehow the answer I expected. Thanks for your time and attention @Jakumi. I'll accept your answer as long as I implement it to my code.

Comment: I do like more elaborated solutions :) It is indeed easier to change how I define some routes attributes like `controller -> _controller` and filter them out by the underscore.

Comment: @gpaulini it is elegant and simple. only drawback being, that it's a "hidden" contract, which might be alright if it is mentioned at some relevant locations (e.g. docs in code) ;o)